# R Cross-correlation via multiple columns

Tags: r, math, correlation

I have a data table like this:

```
> head(my_data)
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1 36045 49933 41622 29491 34393
2 36874 44752 44158 40561 36045
3 45008 51964 58015 32733 29491
4 44830 72017 60434 40347 40561
5 48553 65470 49933 38842 32733
6 52028 64955 44752 41622 40347
```

I have already learned how to find correlation via multiple columns:

```
> head(cor(my_data)[,])
          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
V1 1.0000000 0.4621777 0.7985130 0.9490929 0.9045297
V2 0.4621777 1.0000000 0.8041824 0.4201712 0.1583757
V3 0.7985130 0.8041824 1.0000000 0.7466672 0.5889458
V4 0.9490929 0.4201712 0.7466672 1.0000000 0.8672321
V5 0.9045297 0.1583757 0.5889458 0.8672321 1.0000000
```

I've tried a lot, but could not reach my goal to find maximum absolute value for cross-correlation with **ccf** funtion among every pair. Thanks a lot in advance for all your answers!

Comment: is it maximum of absolute value or absolute value of maximum?

Comment: I'm looking for the maximum of absolute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat
#         V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
# [1,] 36045 49933 41622 29491 34393
# [2,] 36874 44752 44158 40561 36045
# [3,] 45008 51964 58015 32733 29491
# [4,] 44830 72017 60434 40347 40561
# [5,] 48553 65470 49933 38842 32733
# [6,] 52028 64955 44752 41622 40347

class(mat)
# [1] "matrix"

combins <- combn(colnames(mat), 2)

a1 <- apply(combins, 2,
            FUN = function(x){ccf(mat[, x[1]], mat[, x[2]])})

abs_max_ccf <- unlist(lapply(a1, function(x) abs(max(x$acf))))

names(abs_max_ccf) <- apply(combins, 2, function(x) paste0(x[1], x[2], collapse = ''))

abs_max_ccf
#      V1V2      V1V3      V1V4      V1V5      V2V3      V2V4      V2V5      V3V4      V3V5      V4V5 
# 0.7460529 0.4450512 0.5167570 0.4672099 0.8028452 0.4944933 0.5220862 0.4076768 0.2884272 0.8494897
```

**Verify Results:** Extract two columns from `mat`: `V1` and `V2` and perform absolute maximum of ccf.

```
abs(max(ccf(mat[, "V1"], mat[, "V2"])$acf))
# [1] 0.7460529
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help in resolving this issue!

Comment: For maximum of absolute value, you get the absolute values first and then the maximum. It will be like: max(abs(x$acf))