# How to detect shifted values between columns in a df?

Tags: r

Is it possible to determine shifted values in several columns of a `df`, obtained as a result of e.g. import error? Consider this example:

```
 year  sampleA  sampleB sampleC
 2012  22       34      NA
 2013  15       22      NA
 2014  39       15      22
 2015  41       39      15
 2016  NA       41      39
```

In this case, all columns have the same sequences of numbers, either in the middle of other sequence (like in `sampleB`) or with NA's (like in `sampleA` and `sampleC`).

If I had a df with several hundred columns, how could I identify such problematic columns?

Comment: What is the result you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate [cross correlation between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778220/13513328) to identify similar sequences :

```r
set.seed(1)
seq1 <- runif(100,0,100) 
seq2 <- runif(100,0,100)
seq3 <- c(rep(NA,10),seq1)[1:100]
seq4 <- c(runif(10,0,100),seq2)[1:100]

df <- data.frame(seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4)

colcombinations <- combn(colnames(df), 2)
crosscor <- apply(colcombinations, 2,
            FUN = function(x){ccf(na.omit(df[, x[1]]), na.omit(df[, x[2]]),lag.max=50)})

max_crosscor <- unlist(lapply(crosscor, function(x) abs(max(x$acf))))

rbind(colcombinations,round(max_crosscor,2))
#>      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  
#> [1,] "seq1" "seq1" "seq1" "seq2" "seq2" "seq3"
#> [2,] "seq2" "seq3" "seq4" "seq3" "seq4" "seq4"
#> [3,] "0.21" "1"    "0.22" "0.21" "0.9"  "0.21"
```

Columns having a maximum cross-correlation near 1 are similar.